# How to hide others checkboxes in another block created in ACF when one checkbox is selected?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, wordpress-gutenberg

I'm having difficulty trying to get a function to work. I created a block in ACF with a checkbox to run a function when a post is being saved. What I'm trying to do is hide other checkboxes when one checkbox is selected. For example, if I added a block, select that checkbox in the block and then add another block, the checkbox in the other block should be hidden.

Here's an example of my code. The check boxes show up when you click on the blue box:

```js
$(document).on( "click", '#one_image_set_thumbnail', function() {
        $(".acf-field-602d961d31e16").css({'height':'inherit','overflow':'inherit','border-top':'0','padding':'0 0 19.5px'});
});
    $(document).on("click", "#one_image_set_thumbnail,#one_image_feature_image input", function () {
        if ($("#one_image_feature_image input").is(":checked")) {
            $("#one_image_feature_image label").css("display", "none");
            $("#one_image_feature_image .acf-label").text("Thumbnail has been selected");
        } else {
            $("#one_image_feature_image label").css("display", "block");
            $("#one_image_feature_image .acf-label").text("");
        };
    });
```

```css
#one_image_set_thumbnail {width:120px;height:30.5px;border-color: #007cba;
background: #008dd4;border-radius: 3px;margin-bottom:10px}
#one_image_feature_image {height:0;overflow:hidden}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="one_image_set_thumbnail">
</div>
<div id="one_image_feature_image" class="acf-field-602d961d31e16">
  <div class="acf-label"></div>
  <div class="acf-input">
    <label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="acf-block_603630f96e87b-field_602d961d31e16-one_img_set_feat_img" name="acf-block_603630f96e87b[field_602d961d31e16][]" value="one_img_set_feat_img">Set featured image
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="one_image_set_thumbnail">
</div>
<div id="one_image_feature_image" class="acf-field-602d961d31e16">
  <div class="acf-label"></div>
  <div class="acf-input">
    <label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="acf-block_603631086e87c-field_602d961d31e16-one_img_set_feat_img" name="acf-block_603631086e87c[field_602d961d31e16][]" value="one_img_set_feat_img">Set featured image
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.When you are trying to perform an event on a bunch of html element then use `class` to do it. `id` used as a unique identifier to perform an event only on one html throughout the page.

2.Simplify your code like below:

```
$(document).on( "click", '.one_image_set_thumbnail', function() {
  $(this).next('.one_image_feature_image').css({
    'height':'inherit',
    'overflow':'inherit',
    'border-top':'0',
    'padding':'0 0 19.5px'
  });
});

$(document).on("click","input[type=checkbox]",function(){
  $('.acf-input').hide();
  $('.one_image_feature_image').find('.acf-label').text("");
  if($(this).is(":checked")){
    $(this).closest('.acf-input').show();
    $(this).closest('.one_image_feature_image').find('.acf-label').text("Thumbnail has been selected");
  }
  
});
```

Working snippet:

```js
$(document).on( "click", '.one_image_set_thumbnail', function() {
  $(this).next('.one_image_feature_image').css({
    'height':'inherit',
    'overflow':'inherit',
    'border-top':'0',
    'padding':'0 0 19.5px'
  });
});

$(document).on("click","input[type=checkbox]",function(){
  $('.acf-input').hide();
  $('.one_image_feature_image').find('.acf-label').text("");
  if($(this).is(":checked")){
    $(this).closest('.acf-input').show();
    $(this).closest('.one_image_feature_image').find('.acf-label').text("Thumbnail has been selected");
  }
});
```

```css
/*instead of # use . now*/
.one_image_set_thumbnail {
  width:120px;
  height:30.5px;
  border-color: #007cba;
  background: #008dd4;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin-bottom:10px
}
/*instead of # use . now*/
.one_image_feature_image {
  height:0;
  overflow:hidden
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- use class -->
<div class="one_image_set_thumbnail"></div>
<div class="one_image_feature_image acf-field-602d961d31e16"><!-- use class -->
  <div class="acf-label"></div>
  <div class="acf-input">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" id="acf-block_603630f96e87b-field_602d961d31e16-one_img_set_feat_img" name="acf-block_603630f96e87b[field_602d961d31e16][]" value="one_img_set_feat_img">Set featured image
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- use class -->
<div class="one_image_set_thumbnail"></div>
<div class="one_image_feature_image acf-field-602d961d31e16"><!-- use class -->
  <div class="acf-label"></div>
  <div class="acf-input">
    <label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="acf-block_603631086e87c-field_602d961d31e16-one_img_set_feat_img" name="acf-block_603631086e87c[field_602d961d31e16][]" value="one_img_set_feat_img">Set featured image
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note:- check HTML comment `<!-- use class -->` where I suggested you to add class, as well as check CSS modifications too

Answer (score 1):

Whenever your `checkbox` is checked you can use `.not()` to exclude other divs and hide them if they are shown . Also , i have use `.next()` , `.parent()` , `closest()` just to traverse *DOM* .

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$(document).on("click", '.one_image_set_thumbnail', function() {
  $(this).next(".acf-field-602d961d31e16").find(".acf-input").css("display", "block"); //show acf div ..
  $(this).next(".acf-field-602d961d31e16").css({
    'height': 'inherit',
    'overflow': 'inherit',
    'border-top': '0',
    'padding': '0 0 19.5px'
  });
});
//on click of input
$(document).on("click", ".one_image_feature_image input", function() {
  if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
    $(this).parent().css("display", "none"); //hide label
    $(this).closest('.one_image_feature_image').find(".acf-label").text("Thumbnail has been selected");
    $(".acf-input").not($(this).closest(".acf-input")).css("display", "none"); //hide other acf input div

  } else {
    $(this).parent().css("display", "block");
    $(this).closest('.one_image_feature_image').find(".acf-label").text("");
  };
});
```

```css
.one_image_set_thumbnail {
  width: 120px;
  height: 30.5px;
  border-color: #007cba;
  background: #008dd4;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin-bottom: 10px
}

.one_image_feature_image {
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="one_image_set_thumbnail">
</div>
<div class="acf-field-602d961d31e16 one_image_feature_image">
  <div class="acf-label"></div>
  <div class="acf-input">
    <label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="acf-block_603630f96e87b-field_602d961d31e16-one_img_set_feat_img" name="acf-block_603630f96e87b[field_602d961d31e16][]" value="one_img_set_feat_img">Set featured image
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="one_image_set_thumbnail">
</div>
<div class="acf-field-602d961d31e16 one_image_feature_image">
  <div class="acf-label"></div>
  <div class="acf-input">
    <label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="acf-block_603630f96e87b-field_602d961d31e16-one_img_set_feat_img" name="acf-block_603630f96e87b[field_602d961d31e16][]" value="one_img_set_feat_img">Set featured image
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Read here for more information :

https://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/

Comment: Thanks for the help. Just like the reply above, this isn't what I was asking for. I was asking help to to hide the other checkbox when one is selected. Here's a photo of what I'm trying to accomplish - https://i.imgur.com/EB1mUdT.png

Comment: yes above code do that did you test it ? Also i have use class here because you cannot have same ids . This line `$(".acf-input").not($(this).closest(".acf-input")).css("display", "none");` do that .